# Scrolling, zoomed in, background

Tags: java, android, matrix, android-canvas

I have an image of a racetrack taken from the top angle. I would like to zoom this image in by about a factor of 2. 
A car will move over the background, the background, since it's zoomed in, should panorate and follow the car as it moves.

I've managed to zoom a background image in, but im having a bit trouble making it follow the car.

This is what i got so far:

```
        float height = (float) background.getHeight();
        float width = (float) background.getWidth();

        float newLeft = 0
        float newTop = 0;
        float newWidth = background.getWidth() * 2; //zoom in effect
        float newHeight = background.getHeight() * 2; //zoom in effect

        Matrix mat = new Matrix();
        mat.postTranslate(newLeft, newTop);
        mat.setScale(newWidth / width, newHeight / height);
        canvas.drawBitmap(background, mat, new Paint());
```

It gives me a zoomed in background, but I don't know how to move this zoom around on image.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it by scaling the canvas itself before drawing the background onto it!

```
canvas.scale(x,y);
canvas.drawBitmap();
```